# cant find R.java

Tags: android, r.java-file

Am new to android. I just started studying android and for practicing i created a project "Temperature Converter" under package "`de.vogella.android.temperature`" and main activity as "ConvertActivity".

On creating project I found errors in

```
1. ConvertActivity.java as R.cannot b resolved
2. AndroidManifest.xml file as "the markup in document following the root element must be well formed"
3. no R.java in gen folder
```

Comment: Just check your XML file also. If you have any mistaken there then, R file cannot be generated.

Comment: cleaning/rebuilding your project will generate the R file if there are no compile errors. if the R file is still missing after a clean rebuild, open up the Error log and see whats the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should solve the problem :)

1)run this in a terminal:
    rm ~/.android/debug.keystore

2)rebuild your project: go to Project –> Clean –> Clean projects selected below –> check your project –> OK

Comment: Following errors were shown after cleaning project Parser exception for /home/tony/workspace/Temperature Converter/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-07-31 00:02:43 - Temperature Converter] Parser exception for /Temperature Converter/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: That's probably something wrong with your AndroidManifest.xml. Double check it and your other xml files and see if there are any errors.

Comment: i agree with @Stark did you check your xml config file?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Remove the import of the R file.
2. Then clean the project.